# Deselect Radio Button if another one is selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Considering the following markup:

```
<form>

<div class="project">
<ul class="choice">
    <li><label for="firstchoice_1">First choice</label><input type="radio" name="firstchoice" value="1" id="firstchoice_1" /></li>
    <li><label for="secondchoice_1">Second choice</label><input type="radio" name="secondchoice" value="1" id="secondchoice_1" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="project">
<ul class="choice">
    <li><label for="firstchoice_2">First choice</label><input type="radio" name="firstchoice" value="2" id="firstchoice_2" /></li>
    <li><label for="secondchoice_2">Second choice</label><input type="radio" name="secondchoice" value="2" id="secondchoice_2" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

</form>
```

What I want to do is to disable one if the radio button in every `.project` group whenever the other one was selected (so only `First choice` or `Second choice` in every group can be selected). What I know how to do is to disable one specific radio button in one specific case but I don't know how to generalize this as they may are a hundred of such `.project` groups.

**Edit**: Please note that only of the whole `First choice` (and vice versa) can be selected. The same name is already used for that one. The same `name` attribute is used throughout the whole markup. There are only two different `name`s.

Comment: This is a worthwhile question! I'm working on a mobile app where each radio button toggles a separate form, so the buttons aren't part of the same group..so the native behavior no longer works.

Answer (score 14):

Simply give them the same `name` but different `value`s; this will then happen automatically as this is how radio buttons are designed.

Answer (score 3):

If you give same `name` to a set of radio buttons then they automatically check/uncheck whenever you click on them. But the ids should be unique for each of the radio buttons which is not there your markup. Take a look at this working demo, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fAAmL/)**

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen to the change event on all radio buttons. When any one of them changes, you'll check to see whether it got checked. If it did, you'll then uncheck all the other radio buttons within that `.project`:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function()
{
    if (this.checked)
    {
        $(this).closest('.project')
            .find('input[type=radio]').not(this)
            .prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems promising, I'll check this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the same name for all buttons in a group. Then the browser does the disabling automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the same name for all buttons in a group. Then the browser does the disabling automatically.

u can change the id for different values if u want

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(function(){
 if($(this).attr('checked')==true)
    {
        $('.project').not(this).attr('checked',false);
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

<div class="project">
<ul class="choice">
    <li><label for="firstchoice_1">First choice</label><input type="radio" name="firstchoice" value="1" id="firstchoice_1" /></li>
    <li><label for="secondchoice_1">Second choice</label><input type="radio" name="secondchoice" value="1" id="secondchoice_1" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="project">
<ul class="choice">
    <li><label for="firstchoice_2">First choice</label><input type="radio" name="firstchoice" value="2" id="firstchoice_2" /></li>
    <li><label for="secondchoice_2">Second choice</label><input type="radio" name="secondchoice" value="2" id="secondchoice_2" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

</form>
```

Or if you use same name for multiple element then you will able to select one among them.